Proving covariance
The question goes:
Two very important properties of a random variable (say $ x \epsilon R^d $ with its probability distribution function (p.d.f) being p) are,

mean i.e µ=E[x]=∫ xp(x)dx
covariance i.e $ Σ=E[(x−E[x])(x−E[x])^T] $

Prove the following equality, $ Σ=E[xx^T]−E[x]E[x]^T $
If we expand Σ from the definition,
$ Σ = E[xx^T - xE[x]^T - E[x]x^T + E[x]E[x]^T] $
$ Σ = E[xx^T] - E[x]E[x]^T - E[x^T]E[x] + E[x]E[x]^T $
$ Σ = E[xx^T] - E[x]E[x^T] $
What am I doing wrong?

So mean of a vector is equal to the mean of the vector.T right?

Nothing’s wrong in your work. When $x$ is a column vector, namely,
$$
x=\pmatrix{x_1\\ x_2\\ \vdots\\ x_d},
$$
its expectation is given by
$$
E(x)=E\pmatrix{x_1\\ x_2\\ \vdots\\ x_d}=\pmatrix{E(x_1)\\ E(x_2)\\ \vdots\\ E(x_d)}.
$$
Similarly, for a row vector $x^T=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_d)$, we have
$$
E(x^T)=E(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_d)=\left(E(x_1), E(x_2), \ldots, E(x_d)\right).
$$
Therefore $E(x^T)=\left(E(x_1), E(x_2), \ldots, E(x_d)\right)=E(x)^T$.
